# Dividing and spacing

Tags: c#

I need to divide a variable distance in a very specific way.   The spacing for the divisions must be 40 units minimum, and 80 units maximum.

I've tried several different various of this code but I am struggling to wrap my head around how to include the min/max variable in my division.

```
double totaldist = X; 
double division = totaldist / 80;
double roundup = Math.Ceiling(division);
double space = totaldist / roundup;

double increment = 0;
while (increment < totaldist)
{
increment = increment + space;
}
```

The attached code is obviously short of what I want to accomplish, I'm not sure how to bridge the gap.  Thank you

Comment: What does the min max do? I would help you but I don't understand.

Comment: Can you provide a sample with given data and expected result?

Comment: Why don't you just divide your distance by 60?

Comment: @MaximKhanov Maybe image helps?  [link](https://ibb.co/W2v7fJG)

Comment: @CaiusJard I think dividing by less than 80 when not necessary will make more items than needed in some cases.

Comment: @MaxEffects So you want to find an even divisor given that the divisor is in the range 40 to 80?

Comment: @MaximKhanov yea, believe that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Do you say even, do you mean even number like two, four, six…

Comment: Are you looking for a way to divide a Particula distance X into the lowest number of segments with no remainder.? And the number of segments will be between 40 and 80?

Comment: @CaiusJard sorry, even meaning equal distances.

Comment: @CaiusJard that sounds exactly right

Comment: _in a very specific way._ Unfortunately your post makes it clear that you do not really know the specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all you have to do is loop over all the possible divisors and pick the best one. The simplest way to accomplish this is as follows:

```
public static int remainder(int totalDist)
{
    double minRemainder = (totalDist % 40) / 40;
    int bestDivision = 40;
    for (var i = 40; i <= 80; i++)
    {
        double cRemainder = (totalDist % i) / i;
        if (totalDist % i == 0) return i;
        else if (cRemainder < minRemainder) { minRemainder = cRemainder; bestDivision = i; }
    }
    return bestDivision;
}
```

This will always return the closest result. Even if there is no real solution, it will still provide an approximate answer as a fallback.

Comment: @MaxEffects No Problem ;)

Comment: You probably want `for (var i = 40; i <= 80; i++)`, because looks like max value is inclusive

Answer (score 0):

I'd test every divisor for mod 0 (no remainder)

```
int d = 420;
int s = 40;
for(; s <= 80; s++){
  if(d%s==0)
    break;
}
if(s==81)
  Console.Write("There is no suitable divisor");
else
  Console.Write($"{d} divides into {s} segments of {d/s} with no remainder");
```

If you want to minimise the segment length (greater number of segments) start at 80 and work towards 40 in the loop instead - set your d to 480, start at 80 and you should get "80 segments of length 6" rather than "40 segments of length 12"

You can even get cute with your loop and have no body:

```
for(; s <= 80 && d%s > 0; s++){ }
```

But it's not quite so readable/self explanatory

Comment: Ohh minigolf ;)